# HTML/CSS - All text elements are 23 pixels wide no matter the text content

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, width

I have some text elements (`h1`) and they all for some reason are the same width, even while having different text in them.

HTML:

```
<h1 class="main-text" id="one">text</h1>
<h1 class="main-text" id="two">texttextext</h1>
<h1 class="main-text" id="three">texttextexttexttextext</h1>
```

CSS:

```
.main-text {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  text-align: center;
  color: #848484;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

For some reason, when I run the following JS code:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("one").offsetWidth)
console.log(document.getElementById("two").offsetWidth)
console.log(document.getElementById("three").offsetWidth)
```

All of them log as `23`. My screen width is 1920px if that helps. Is there something in my CSS that might be causing this?

Comment: It becomes too difficult to understand what you actually want to achieve especially for HTML and CSS related questions (in general) until and unless you provide some screenshot or code snippet.

Comment: You definitely have to share the code - this could be anything. A wrapper could be causing this or anything. Without additional information its hard to debug.

Comment: where are you include the JS ? am pretty sure you are running the JS before the full HTML is rendred

Comment: @TemaniAfif nope im running it with `window.onload = myFunction` in the head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h` is a block level element , so it will try to occupy the full width of the parent

Use `display:inline-block` to set the width according to the content and for line break use `<br/>`

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("one").offsetWidth)
console.log(document.getElementById("two").offsetWidth)
console.log(document.getElementById("three").offsetWidth)
```

```css
.main-text {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  text-align: center;
  color: #848484;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="main-text" id="one">text</h1>
<br/>
<h1 class="main-text" id="two">texttextext</h1>
<br/>
<h1 class="main-text" id="three">texttextexttexttextext</h1>
```

Comment: You can actually see it working in the example above. The log is displayed right there.

Comment: @pj100 yeah I see that but im not sure why its different for me

Answer (score 1):

So this is happening because h1 is a block level element. If you add `display:inline-block` to your CSS you'll see the difference in offset. With the default `display:block` the element will fill the width of the page, even though you're pushing it over 50% and then resetting it.